# Normalize many-to-many data

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, database-normalization

I have a non-normalized database that establishes a many-to-many relationship this way.

Article table:

```
| id  | category_ids | some_more_columns |
| --- | ------------ | ----------------- |
| 1   | []           |                   |
| 2   | [1, 2]       |                   |
| 3   | [3]          |                   |
```

Category table:

```
| id  | some_more_columns |
| --- | ----------------- |
| 1   |                   |
| 2   |                   |
| 3   |                   |
```

I want to make a proper many-to-many relationship like:

Article table:

```
| id  | some_more_columns |
| --- | ----------------- |
| 1   |                   |
| 2   |                   |
| 3   |                   |
```

Category table:

```
| id  | some_more_columns |
| --- | ----------------- |
| 1   |                   |
| 2   |                   |
| 3   |                   |
```

Finally, Article has categories table:

```
| id  | article_id | category_id |
| --- | ---------- | ----------- |
| 1   | 2          | 1           |
| 2   | 2          | 2           |
| 3   | 3          | 3           |
```

I want to write a script to populate the table of Article_has_categories using the column of category_ids in the Article table in MySQL.
I'm very young in SQL, so this is very overwhelming.
Please shine some light!

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: it returns '5.7.35-log'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pivot the array of category id's into individual rows. You can do this by joining to a derived table of integers. It looks like the array is in JSON format, so you can use [MySQL's JSON_EXTRACT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract).

```
INSERT INTO Article_has_categories (article_id, category_id)
 SELECT a.id, JSON_EXTRACT(a.category_ids, CONCAT('$[', num.num, ']'))
 FROM Article AS a
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS num
  UNION SELECT 1 
  UNION SELECT 2 
  UNION SELECT 3 
  ...as many as the longest list of category_id...
 ) AS num
 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(a.category_ids, CONCAT('$[', num.num, ']'));
```

(I have not tested this, but it should get you started.)

If that is too difficult, then an alternative solution is to develop code to do the conversion. You will have to write a program to fetch the `category_ids` array, explode it into individual values, and loop over them to insert rows into `Article_has_categories`.

If this is still too difficult, then you should hire a software developer to do it.

Comment: Your solution works like charm!! Thank you so much! You saved the day.

Comment: For other beginners like myself, who try to copy this solution. With all due respect to @BillKarwin, there were 2 missing semicolons. One at the end of 2nd line, one at the end of the last line.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited to fix the syntax. The missing symbols are parentheses, not semicolons.

Comment: Parentheses they are! lol